# How to add the contents of a folder to a jar file without extracting it in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How do you add the contents of a folder to a jar file without extracting it?

I would like to run it in a batch file.

I started using 7zip

```
7za x test.jar
copy test1 test
7za a test.zip -tzip
move test.zip test.jar
```

[7zip cmd download](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip)

Comment: Can you be more specific? You've just repeated the tile of the question as the body. Do you mean doing it programmatically? Do you mean Java classes, or just random files? The answer to the question as asked is to open the .jar with any Zip program and copy the folder in... but I suspect that's not what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 7zip.  Open the archive and then drag the folder to the place where you want to place.